# Reading next row of *.txt column inside ArcPy for loop for batch process?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I'm not sure how to approach this problem with python, but in plain english, I'd like to rename rasters with the names given in the *.txt file (see screenshot) and concatenate the basename given by the text file with the original file extension. For example I would like snowdepthN0001.tif to be renamed to 12-Jul_02.tif

So far to check my progress, I've only been able to print single letters or characters from the text file per row rather than the all the characters within each row.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

RASTER_DIR = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTRaster"
env.workspace = RASTER_DIR

date_file = open("timetest.txt", "r")

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(raster)

    for row in date_file.read():
        print row
        fileNameParts = row
        fileNameParts = fileName.split('_')
        compactFileName = row + fileExtension
        arcpy.Rename_management(raster,compactFileName)

date_file.close()
```

[image]

Here's what the raster names look like (there are 90 of them).

[image]

Comment: What do the raster names look like? For example, what does the raster name for 12-Jul_02 look like and what would you like the final product to look like?  It would be helpful if you could edit your question with this information.

Comment: Does the first row in the .txt file align with the first raster (assuming the raster list was sorted alphabetically)? For example, should the final raster name look like the following: `snowdepthN0001_12-Jul_02.tif`?

Comment: No, just want to replace the entire original name with what's being read from the text file rows. The final product should be 12-Jul_02.tif, 12-Jul_03.tif, 12-Jul_04.tif, and so on, so that the alphabetical order of the rasters corresponds to the order of rows in the text file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *for row in date_file:*? I can't find a quick example but the iteration is line by line (assuming each line finishes properly). Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array for other methods (read entire file into a list/array)... The reason you're getting individual characters is that read() will read a single character but readline() will read a line from a text file.

Comment: You're correct, I changed it to "for row in date_file:" and it prints the entire first row of the text file - "12-Jul_02". Now it says there's a problem executing the "arcpy.Rename_management" line. Failed to rename raster dataset. Failed to execute (Rename).

Comment: If I instead define compactFileName as fileNameParts + fileExtension I get TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "unicode") to list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this sort of renaming by utilizing [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).  The general idea is to add an index with each raster name and then call that index to reference the specific item in the text file list.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\input\rasters'

txtfile = r'C:\path\to\textfile.txt'

# Generate a list of items from text file
with open(txtfile, 'r') as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f]

# List all rasters
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
rasters2 = list(enumerate(rasters))

# Loop through rasters and do the renaming
for i,r in rasters2:
    outname = names[i] + ".tif"
    arcpy.Rename_management(r, outname)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using ArcGIS (arcpy) in this case and do this using a pure Python solution. This will be faster and much cleaner. Since you are renaming tif files you do not need to use ListRasters() or arcpy.Rename()...see this example:

```
import os
import glob

def rename_files(new_names_file, file_folder):
    files_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_folder, '*.tif'))

    fp = open(new_names_file, 'rb')
    for tif_file in sorted(files_list):
        new_name = fp.next().strip()
        os.rename(tif_file, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(tif_file), "{0}.tif".format(new_name)))

    fp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names_file = r"C:\GISData\tiffs\new_names.txt"
    tif_folder = r"C:\GISData\tiffs"
    rename_files(names_file, tif_folder)
```

Comment: +1 Pure Python solutions are always nice.  Additionally, Python scripts run faster when utilizing functions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11241523/1446289.